# Elasticsearch python api GET index stats

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm using python [ES client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) and I would like to query stats about indexes. More concretely, I'm looking for this endpoint:

```
GET /_stats
```

Does anyone know how to use the [IndicesClient](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient) class mentioned in the docs?

Comment: You are looking for [stats](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.stats) method? You can do `es.indices.stats(...)`, Where `es` is your `Elasticsearch` object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")
es.indices.stats(index=<your_index_name>)
```